# How to write formula dynamically in excel in multiple cells using xlsxwriter module?

Tags: python

I have created excel workbook contains some sheets and I have added one sheet and I want to use a formula in that sheet taking values from another sheet, for this I'll have to use formula dynamically using a for loop but when I passed cell2 and cell3 as a variable inside the formula I am getting and error:

```
File "<ipython-input-26-a7cfb4c63c79>", line 8, in <module>
ws2.write_formula(0, 1, '=COUNTIFS(Deviation!%s:%s,"<=-15%")' %(cell2, cell3))

TypeError: not enough arguments for format string`
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
for cl in range(1, 32):
    cell2 = xl_rowcol_to_cell(1, cl)
    cell3 = xl_rowcol_to_cell(432, cl)
    ws2.write_formula(0, 1, '=COUNTIFS(Deviation!%s:%s,"<=-15%")' %(cell2, cell3))
```

Kindly help, how to achieve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplify your problem, elimitate the excel stuff and use the string formatting with *print* alone:

> ```
> cell2 = "A1"
> cell3 = "B22"
>
> # TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
> print('=COUNTIFS(Deviation!%s:%s,"<=-15%")' %(cell2, cell3))
> ```

Then look into [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) - your string contains a `'%'` as literal character - this confuses python.

The documentation tells you to double up on `%` to print a literal one:

> **The conversion types are:**
>      [snipp unimportant ones]
>      `'%'` -> No argument is converted, results in a '%' character in the result.

```
cell2 = "A1"
cell3 = "B22"

formatstr = '=COUNTIFS(Deviation!%s:%s,"<=-15%%")' %(cell2, cell3)
print(formatstr)

# ws2.write_formula(0, 1, formatstr) # use formatted string
```

Voilà. Fixed. Output:

```
=COUNTIFS(Deviation!A1:B22,"<=-15%")
```

---

Easier would be using `str.format` or string interpolation (Python 3.x):

```
print('=COUNTIFS(Deviation!{}:{},"<=-15%%")'.format(cell2, cell3) )
print(f'=COUNTIFS(Deviation!{cell2}:{cell3},"<=-15%%")') # python 3
```